# What is the fastest way to get from Courmayeur/Aosta to Milan?

Tags: transportation, france, italy, milan

We will be crossing the Italian/French border through Mont Blanc via cable cars, which we heard through Rick Steve's article: [From France to Italy over Mont Blanc](http://www.ricksteves.com/plan/destinations/france/chamonix.htm). 
We will be starting off in Chamonix and arriving in Courmayeur. What's the fastest (and relatively cost-effective) way to get to Milan from Courmayeur?

Comment: If you have strong convincing skills, the fastest - and most expensive- is [helicopter](http://www.alpesexploration.com/Programmes/Heliski_Chamonix.htm).

Comment: The **fastest** could be Blablacar, but you have to be lucky to find a direct driver. You may need to stop in Torino.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have at least two options:

### Bus + train

The nearest railway station to Courmayeur is Pré-St. Didier, approximately 6 km from Courmayeur.

To get from Courmayeur to Pré-St. Didier, take a bus with [SAVDA](http://www.savda.it/). This bus departs several times per day and takes 10 minutes. You need [busline 176](http://www.savda.it/public/linee/allegati/176_it.pdf). It's also possible to take this bus all the way to Aosta, but it's perhaps more interesting to change to the train.

For the train from either Pré-St. Didier or Aosta to Milano Centrale, you can use the search engine at [trenitalia.com](http://www.trenitalia.com/cms/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=ad1ce14114bc9110VgnVCM10000080a3e90aRCRD). To get from Pré-St. Didier to Milano Centrale, you need to take the train to Aosta, then Aosta–Ivrea, Ivrea–Chivasso and Chivasso–Milano. This route takes 4 hours 18 minutes and costs €17.40. There are other routes that take longer.

Note that **[the HAFAS international journey planner](http://plannerint.b-rail.be/bin/query.exe/en?L=b-rail), used by bahn.de and other websites, is incomplete**. It claims a journey trip from Pré St. Didier to Milan takes 6 hours 55 minutes, by train to Aoste, bus to Martigny, train via Visp to Milano. This is neither fastest nor cheapest!

### By bus all the way

SAVDA also operate [a direct bus from Courmayeur to Milano](http://www.savda.it/it/documenti/57/orario-invernale-2012-2013.php). Times and frequency depend on the time of day. The bus takes approximately 3½–4 hours, and costs €18.

Answer (score 2):

Take the bus. There are direct ones. Otherwise you have to change in Aosta. The journey is less than 4 hours. The price for a single ticket us 18 EUR and for a return ticket 32.50 EUR.

For more informstion, check the following site:

http://www.savda.it

Schedules are available here:

http://www.savda.it/it/35/valle-d-aosta-milano.php