# How to get from Courmayeur to Milano?

Tags: transit, transportation, italy, alps, milan

I don't speak Italian but I found some connections from Courmayeur to Milano. Option with train is long, uncomfortable (4 changes) and expensive in comparison to one-change bus connection, but I can't buy tickets in advance via WWW and don't know if there will be enough seats for my group.

I don't know this country, so I'm afraid if it is wise to count on enough seats and just come to the bus at the right time… In addition, there could be some delays because of bike rides as far as I know. Are there some ways to buy tickets on the spot? Maybe ways to book? We can't be too late to Milano.

Comment: why you can't buy the ticket in advance online?

Comment: and how many people we are talking about?

Comment: in addition http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-from-courmayeur-aosta-to-milan

Comment: Unfortunately answers in this former question are outdated in 2014.

Comment: There are 3 of us and we have limited access to web. We can pay only with real money, no Paypal etc. so we cant online.

Comment: the answers in the other question are not outdated, SAVDA still operates the bus line. I think you can find place for 3.

Comment: Thanks.
I know about SAVDA, there is one connection with one change (so no direct one from those answers). I hope that there will be enough place.

Answer (score 4):

As already suggested in the previous comments, SAVDA provides a one-change connection from Courmayeur to Milan.

You can find the schedule and other info [here](http://www.savda.it/public/linee/allegati/407_it.pdf).

Since you are not familiar with the Italian language, I will report some significant information below:

- you can buy tickets directly on the bus, but it will cost you € 2
  more per ticket.
- you can buy tickets at the travel agency "Agenzia Mont Blanc T.O.", Piazzale Monte Bianco 3 in Courmayeur
- You can bring a hand luggage (max 5 kg) and another baggage in the trunk (max 10 kg extendable to 30 kg with a surcharge)
- you cannot reserve seats unless you have a seasonal ticket.

It should be not a problem to find three seats. I would suggest being at the bus station in advance, just to be sure and be able to choose the seats (I believe half an hour is more than enough, but ask the travel agency).